# Как продлевается корневой сертификат?

Tags: ssl, криптография, шифрование, openssl, сертификат

Для внутрених нужд использую сертификаты подписанные моим CA. Половина срока действия CA уже прошла. Можно ли продлить срок сертификата? Или как правильно производится замена корневого сертификата?

Если я выпускаю промежуточный CA с большим сроком - будет ли он валиден для выпуска новых сертификатов после окончания срока корневого?

Answer (score 0):

Процедура валидации сертификатов описана в [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#page-73)

> Если я выпускаю промежуточный CA с большим сроком - будет ли он валиден для выпуска новых сертификатов после окончания срока корневого?

В RFC 5280 (по ссылке приведённой выше) сформулировано требование:

> (d)  for all x in {1, ..., n}, the certificate was valid at the time in question.

Здесь сертификат с индексом 1 - корневой сертификат. То есть как только срок действия корневого сертификата истекает, все производные сертификаты становятся невалидными.

> Можно ли продлить срок сертификата?

Сертификат нельзя продлить. Можно только заменить на сертификат с тем же публичным ключом и другими notBefore/notAfter. У этого сертификата будет другой serial number и другой fingerprint. Как ни крути, это будет  ДРУГОЙ сертификат.

По-правильному, нужно выпустить новый корневой и промежуточные сертификаты и все новые сертификаты выпускать в этой цепи. Старую цепочку сертификатов оставить для валидации уже выпущенных сертификатов. Клиентам выдать оба корневых сертификата - и старый, и новый. Старым они будут валидировать уже выпущенные сертификаты, а новым - все последующие.

Comment: Если перевыпустить CA с новым сроком, но старым ключем, то им можно валидировать старые выпущенные сертификаты серверов и клиентов?

Comment: Что написано в ваших сертификатах в поле Issuer? Если в новом сертификате в поле Subject будет написано то же самое, то можно. Ещё проверьте, есть ли в сертификатах необязательное поле Issuer unique identifier. Если есть, то в новом корневом сертификате нужно задать поле Subject unique identifierс таким же значением.